# Something is modifying .httaccess

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, htaccess

There is a strange problem, about 2 times a day in our .htacess file the RewriteEngine line is changed fron **on** to **off**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine off
```

We have checked everything, there is no hacking, the file permissions are okay, so I think some Magento setting keeps changing this. Problem is that with the RewriteEngine set to off none of the products are accessible anymore.

Any ideas what do I need to check?

Comment: Just did a quick scan on one of my main projects, which contains a number of modules. The only module that would read/write .htaccess is 'Creare SEO' (do you have that installed?) and the Magento installer does some checks on .htaccess.

Comment: No, I don't have this module installed, but it's a good extension that I will probably use. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Are you hosting the server via anything like Cpanel, Plesk/Odin etc? They have a tendancy to over-ride configs via cron. If using regular Linux distro, have you checked nothing is updating your configs via cron? Might be worth looking in your Magento cron queue, to see what 3rd-party modules are running. `Aoe_Scheduler` is a good module for looking at this, or you can look directly in the SQL table `cron_schedule`.

Comment: Okay, I will take look. I have Aoe_Scheduler installed. This is my suspicion also, that some cron task is overwriting it.

Comment: There are not so many modules which modify this file, and there is certainly none, which sets this to off. I would expect it to be from outside of magento. Either from the hosting side, or the deployment of the Magento itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from an outdated and hacked WordPress blog installed in magento subdirectory.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/111226)

Comment: This is the complete answer, after we deleted the blog the issue disappeared.